# How can I get today published posts by page in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

One page publishes a new post every day (this is not my page). I would like to integrate this with slack and display the content of the post in the messenger. How can I download such posts using facebook api?

When I'm trying to call `GET /{page-id}/feed` it requires 'Page Public Content Access' - is it mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to apply for Page Public Content Access if you want to access data of Pages you do not own - no matter if the data is public on facebook.com.

Comment: Only posts, which are publically available. Even without FB account i can read this data! Still need i above access?

Comment: yes, of course. it does not matter if you can access stuff in public, for automated access with the api you have to get permission.

Comment: If you don't see a difference between accessing the data using the API and manually looking at it on facebook.com then just look at it on facebook.com.